# Publishing web project to azure failed: The "IsolatedCSPack" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: azure

I have web application that I want to publish and upload to windows azure.
I use Visual Studio 2008.
I click on "publish", chose "Create Service Package Only" in "Publish Cloud Service" window, andclick on "OK".
The publish failed tnd the exception is:

> Error   26  The "IsolatedCSPack" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>    at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
>    at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
>    at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.CopyMemoryBlocksToStream(Stream targetStream)
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.WriteToStream(Stream stream)
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOFileItemStream.Save()
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.Save()
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.SaveContainer(Boolean closingFlag)
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.SaveStream(ZipIOLocalFileBlock blockRequestingFlush, Boolean closingFlag)
>    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>    at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>    at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.Close()
>    at System.IO.Packaging.Package.DoClose(PackagePart p)
>    at System.IO.Packaging.Package.DoOperationOnEachPart(PartOperation operation)
>    at System.IO.Packaging.Package.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.PackageCreator.CreateRolePackages(ModelProcessor modelProcessor, PackageManifest applicationManifest, Package applicationPackage)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.PackageCreator.CreatePackage(Stream outputStream)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.ServiceApplicationPackage.CreateServiceApplicationPackage(String serviceModelFileName, String serviceDescriptionFile, Stream output, IPackageSecurity encrypt, Dictionary`2 namedStreamCollection, String userInfo, EventHandler`1 rolePackagePartAddedHandler)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.ServiceApplicationPackage.CreateServiceApplicationPackage(String serviceModelFileName, String serviceDescriptionFile, Stream output, RSACryptoServiceProvider encrypt, Dictionary`2 namedStreamCollection, String userInfo, EventHandler`1 rolePackagePartAddedHandler)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.CSPack.TryCreatePackage(ServiceDefinitionModel sm)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.CSPack.Execute()
>    at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.IsolatedCSPack.RemoteCSPackBridge.Execute(TaskLoggingHelper log, IBuildEngine buildEngine, ITaskHost hostObject, String serviceHostingTasksPath, String output, String serviceDefinitionFile, ITaskItem[] packRoles, Boolean copyOnly, String generateConfigurationFile, Boolean noEncryptPackage, ITaskItem[]& copiedFiles, ITaskItem[]& outputFiles)
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>    at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.IsolatedCSPack.RemoteCSPackBridge.Execute(TaskLoggingHelper log, IBuildEngine buildEngine, ITaskHost hostObject, String serviceHostingTasksPath, String output, String serviceDefinitionFile, ITaskItem[] packRoles, Boolean copyOnly, String generateConfigurationFile, Boolean noEncryptPackage, ITaskItem[]& copiedFiles, ITaskItem[]& outputFiles)
>    at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.IsolatedCSPack.Execute()
>    at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)   C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Cloud Service\v1.0\Microsoft.CloudService.targets    865 5   Starlims.SDMS.Azure

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happened to me before... try restarting the computer (I know... it's a bit "Technical Support" advice - but it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the same problem [someone else posted about](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/0708caf9-593d-47c0-8a66-097b1bdd7490) on the MSDN Azure forum. Their problem was that a resource was being copied into the project with:

- build action = Content
- Copy to Output Directory = Copy if Newer.

They changed the latter to Never and the problem went away.