# CSPack 1.4 crashes with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: azure

I'm having a problem creating a package for a web role that totals up to 380 megabytes on disk. I can get CSPack to run fine when specifying the /copyOnly flag, but as soon as I try to create the actual package file I get an OutOfMemoryException. The problem started after I added around 350 megabytes of static content to the web role project.

I've already found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615777/publishing-web-project-to-azure-failed-the-isolatedcspack-task-failed-unexpect) here on Stack Overflow, but even with all the content set to "Do Not Copy," I still get the same issue with CSPack crashing. Just to verify that the static content is what is causing an issue, I excluded it from my project in Visual Studio and CSPack ran fine from the command line.

Here's the command I'm executing from cmd.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\bin\cspack"  
BizBlimp.Azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef /role:BizBlimp;Build\BizBlimp 
/role:BizBlimp.QueueWorker;Build\BizBlimp.QueueWorker;Biz
Blimp.QueueWorker.dll /sites:BizBlimp;Web;Build\BizBlimp /rolePropertiesFile:Biz
Blimp;properties.txt /rolePropertiesFile:BizBlimp.QueueWorker;properties.txt /ou
t:Build\BizBlimp.Azure.cpkg
```

And here's my project file for my web role: https://gist.github.com/88e776bb611cf6a8521e

I've been banging my head up against this problem for the last couple work days, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: [Link to the same issue on the Microsoft Azure Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/2647a966-b1fb-4eec-8ed4-46ddb472e51a). Looks like this is gaining some attention from an MSFT employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite a lot of static content.  Every time you update your application you'll have to upload that 350mb of stuff.  Have you considered storing the static content in blob storage?  It looks like most of it is images and would sit quite nicely there. I'm sorry this doesn't solve your crash issue, but it will probably make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: I think you're right on that one. The static content is actually sitemaps generated from the database, so I may just switch over to dynamically generating them and caching the results in blob storage. Thanks for the feedback.